# After-death care of a non-Jewish relative

Tags: halacha, gentiles, death, funeral-burial-levaya

If a Jew has been entrusted with the after-death care of a non-Jewish relative, what should be done? Specifically, if the non-Jewish relative requested to be cremated after death, can or should a Jew arrange this? As [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/593/cremations-for-jews/594#594) shows, the reasons not to cremate apply to Gentiles as well as Jews.

Comment: CYLOR is a given here. The question is posed theoretically.

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but are we supposing that the Jew knew of the problematic request in advance, or did he learn of it only after the death?

Comment: My thought was in advance, but I would like to hear answers in both situations.