# Meis Mitzva and Idolatry

Tags: avodah-zarah, kohen-priest, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, funeral-burial-levaya

A Cohen finds a dead body in India

Should he bury it himself and become taamei
OR
Should he inform the nearby village who will then dispose of the body with idolatrous rituals.

The roots of the matter:
Does the idolatrous nature of the village render it an invalid option?
Does the answer change if the body is that of a Jew?

Comment: Why are those the only two options?

Comment: Because those are the only ones I thought of. What other options should be considered?

Comment: Running away. Paying someone to do it without idolatry. Burning it without touching it.

Comment: Burning it is certainly a bad answer. That is actively dishonoring the body.
Running away is not a good answer because there is a mitzva to ensure that the body is buried.
Paying someone else to do it is the best of your answers but  when I placed the scenario in India I meant it as an example of a place where the population was idolatrous. I would consider an idolater who violates his people's "mitzvas" for money to be unscrupulous. Also, this answer does not address the root of the question as to whether the dispensation to become taamei for a mes mitzva still applies.

Comment: How is burning dishonoring the body? And even if it is, whence that you can't/shouldn't do that? Whence the alleged "mitzva to ensure that the body is buried"? Whence that paying someone to not violate a prohibition is unscrupulous? Moreover, whence that such unscrupulousness is forbidden? Finally, whence that any of the above problems (if shown to exist) are worse than the problems of becoming impure or allowing the idolatry to happen??

Comment: 1) On Burning:see top answer for http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/593/cremations-for-jews
2) On Burial of Non Jews: http://www.dinonline.org/2013/03/10/mes-mitzvah-for-non-jews/
3) Since the person you pay is an idol worshiper, by performing a burial without the idolatrous rites would be a bad thing from his point of view.
4) It is not forbidden to entice a non Jew to perform an "aveira" of his religion, but I think this should be avoided. I am looking for an answer that doesn't resort to this.
5. I don't know if any of the above problems are worse. That is the question!!

Comment: tuma met is only by a jew i think

Comment: You are thinking of The tuma that permeates a tent containing a dead body. That does not exist for a non jew (there are gemara opinions who hold that it does). Touching the actual body will transmit tuma.

Comment: @ClintEastwood If you are asking about all that then why isn't it in your question???

Comment: Do you have reason to assume that he isn't obligated to perform the burial himself?

Comment: Allow me to rephrase: Do you have a source to support the obvious assumption you're making that, if he can find someone to perform the burial (within x distance?), he is not obligated to be personally involved with the physical burial act and in fact it is better for him to seek this option?

Comment: I don't assume that. A cohen doesn't have to do the burial if there is a suitable person nearby. I set up the question to imply that there are no ideal people for the burial: only the cohen and the idol worshippers. I am asking if the idol worshippers and their idol worship renders them so unsuitable that the cohen should bury the body himself.

Comment: The question implies that it isn't ideal for him to perform it. Yet he is obligated to. I don't see how you are getting that he shouldn't just because someone else is nearby. What is considered "nearby"?

Comment: Nazir 43b. If there are others around, then the situation isn't that of a mes mitzva and the cohen doesn't bury the body. The ideal person is someone who is allowed to become taamei and  won't perform idolatry with it (or is a necrophiliac). In this manner, the cohen is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already answered in the first Mishna of the 7th Perek of Nazir - also located on Daf 47a of Nazir:

> כהן גדול ונזיר אין מיטמאין לקרוביהן אבל מיטמאין למת מצוה
>
> A Cohen Gadol and a Nazir must not get Tamei for relatives, but must get Tamei for a Meis Mitzva.

A Meis Mitzva gets buried *immediately* - no reason to go to a nearby village. Proof: How far could a Cohen Gadol be at any given time from a village? He was not allowed to sleep outside Jerusalem. (Why? Because he brought a daily Korban - חביטי כהן גדול - and thus had to overnight in Jerusalem, like anybody who brought a Korban.)

However, I have never heard of a non-Jew being referred to as a Meis Mitzva. So the above applies to Jewish abandoned corpses unless we can prove otherwise.

Comment: That is not a good proof. The question was about a regular cohen. In the 40~s of tractate Nazir there is mention of going to a nearby village but the villagers want payment and the cohen is allowed to bury the body. Going to a nearby village is thus still an option.

Answer (score 0):

If the body is a Jew, the situation is regular mes mitzva. If the body is a non-Jew, the situation is a lower grade obligation due to Darchei Noam (ways of peace).

If the body is a Jew, the Kohen should bury the body and not involve non Jews, unless an additional prohibition is involved, such as Shabbos. Shulchan Aruch Yore Deah ~374.

If the body is of a non Jew, the obligation of the Kohen is lesser and does not override his need to stay tahor and he should go to the village, even if they will do idolatry with the body.